# Releasing ivars in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

OK, looking at this:

[Apple docs: Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17)

If you scroll down to dealloc it reads:

"Typically in a dealloc method you should release object instance variables directly (rather than invoking a set accessor and passing nil as the parameter), as illustrated in this example:"

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [property release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

"If you are using the modern runtime and synthesizing the instance variable, however, you cannot access the instance variable directly, so you must invoke the accessor method:"

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self setProperty:nil];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now, I must own at least 15 to 20 books on iOS development.  I can't say that I have ever seen any code in these books proposing that one do anything other than:

```
[someproperty release];
```

Is there a compelling reason to edit a bunch of files of code that works perfectly well to adopt Apple's recommendation?  How about future work?  Or, are they pretty much equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's document appears to apply only if you have synthesize-by-default turned on. If you have it turned off, which seems to be the default case, you need @synthesize, which gives you access to variables directly.

Personally, I do:

```
@synthesize someProperty=_someProperty;
```

just so I can then do:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [_someProperty release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

See [Jeff LaMarche's blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/07/synthesize-by-default.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

On the modern runtime, you no longer have to declare instance variables for properties, nor do you have to write `@synthesize` in the implementation. If your code already has the instance variables declared, then there's no reason to replace code that calls release with a call to a set accessor (the first quote you pasted even states that).

Comment: I was under the impression that not requiring @synthesize was creating problems, so it's now required.

Comment: If you have synthesize-by-default turned on, you don't need @synthesize and you lose direct access. Perfectly clear...